# $request->file('image') result is null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to save an image on a directory and retrieve it on the webpage. I've tried several methods to store an image in a folder, but I got this error.
When I use  `$request->file('image')` result is `null`
I find out solutions and try as that solutions. But I can't fix it.
How can I fix this error and how can I save an image on a file directory

```
 Controller

   public function dili(Request $request)
   {
    $di = new diligent;



    $di->jobtype = $request->jobtype;
    $di->jobC = $request->jobC;
    $di->details = $request->details;
    $di->image = $request->image;



    $imag =  $request->image;

    //dd($imag);
    $path = $imag->getClientOriginalName();

    $destinationPath = public_path('img');

    $imag->move($destinationPath, $path);


    $di->save();
    $de = diligent::all();
    return view('admin')->with('dw', $de);
}
```

web.php

```
 Route::post('/admin', ['as'=> 'image.add', 'uses' => 'diligents@dili' ]);
```

admin.blade.php

```
<form class="row login_form" action="/admin" method="post"  
novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="job" name="jobtype" 
 placeholder="Job " onfocus="this.placeholder = 
 ''"onblur="this.placeholder = 'Job'">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="jobC" name="jobC" placeholder="Job Catagary" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Job Catagary'">
    </div>



<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="details" id="details" rows="4" placeholder="Details" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Details'"></textarea>
</div>

     <div>
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
<p align="left">Upload Image</p>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 form-group col-xl-12">
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="primary-btn">Submit</button>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12 form-group col-xl-12">
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="primary-btn">Update</button>
</div></form>
```

This is the error message I got:

> Call to a member function `getClientOriginalName()` on `string`

Comment: use `$imag = $request->file('image');` instead `$imag =  $request->image;` [Retrieving Uploaded Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)

Comment: when i use $imag = $request->file('image'); i got error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null and dd($imag); is null

Comment: i tried before possible duplicate questions' answer got same error Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null and dd($imag); is null

Comment: then the file is not reaching the controller, you can avoid the exeption with [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-image) or a condition like `if ($request->hasFile('image')) { $imag = $request->file('image'); //... }`. Are you sure you are sending a file?

Comment: I used $image = $request->image; and dd($image); show file. Example as "abc.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for your project.

```
   $image = $request->file('image');

   $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();

   dd($path);
```

By `dd()`you find your image name.
And I hope the error will be removed.